# Calculate an average as a percent?

Tags: sql, postgresql, average

This is a simple problem and I'm surprised I couldn't find an answer to it. 
All I need, is to calculate the average of a column and have the output as a percent.

```
Select round(avg(amount)::numeric, 2)
From Table
```

All I need is to figure out how to make that a percent, right now it comes out as 12345.67, how would I convert that output to a percentage in the query?

Comment: A percentage of what? For example, if the values for the column are: 1000, 2000, 3000 -> the average will be 2000. What percentage value do you think you should get?

Comment: Just an average as a percentage format. There isn't much else.

Comment: A percentage is essentially a fraction. 50% means 50 out of a total of 100. In your case, you have the numerator of the fraction. What is your denominator? Like I asked in my previous comment, if the values for the "amount" column are: 1000, 2000, 3000; then the average will be 2000. What is the output you expect?

Comment: Ah, I see, you are referring to my current output. My current output is correct, I just need to convert the output as a percentage.

Comment: I edited the question to go into detail in that aspect

Comment: So you want your output to be 12345.67%? Just add a "%" sign to the end of the output value?

Comment: Er yeah, if that would be the correct way to do it. I'm just wondering because usually a percentage has a different output from other things. So if that will work, that won't be too hard.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55590/discussion-between-omaer-and-padagomez).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you need something like this:

```
select avg(amount) * 100 / sum(amount) 
from Table
```

Or you can add a percent sign to it like this:

```
select CAST(avg(amount) * 100 / sum(amount)as VARCHAR(max)) + '%' AS Perc
from Table
```

or you can just concatenate a sign to your query:

```
Select CAST(round(avg(amount)::numeric, 2)as VARCHAR(max)) + '%' AS Perc
From Table
```

Comment: that wouldn't be correct as you might end up with an average of 22, and a sum of a million for example. The average might be 22/100, but if there are 10000 rows, you aren't getting the average as a percentage this way.

Comment: @Andrew That depends on what you're after. If you want the average as a percent of the total, this is one way to do it.

Comment: He's getting a percent based on average value opposed to a sum of all rows. Provided that this is what he needs.

Comment: Are these for Postgresql?

Comment: It's written in T-SQL.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet would be to use whatever tools are available to you. But there is a way you can do it as a query.

Try getting the average divided by the sum multiplied by 100.

So you want the average, like below and divided by the sum, and multiplied by 100 to get 100% of the sum.

```
select avg(amount) / sum(amount) * 100
```

Answer (score 1):

Result / Total * 100 = Average

In your case, the Result is: `avg(amount)::numeric`

and the Total is whatever the maximum that `amount` could be.

Comment: So would that be `Result / sum(amount) * 100`? Or can you specify there.